# Как отсортировать значения в csv по времени

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, математика, csv

в общем я совсем не понимаю ничего. Есть файл csv, в нем есть время и дата (вместе с данными).

https://download.ru/files/YAxHRx7V

Как его превратить в несколько csv, где первая категория - разные файлы по дням недели (разбивка на понедельник-пятница), а во втором случае - по часам (один файл превращается в несколько с разбивкой по часам, например, 10.00-10.59, второй файл с данными которые находятся во времени 11.00-11.59 и т.п.).

Буду очень рада помощи.

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
import pandas as pd

fn = r'D:\download\EURUSD_1_2016-06-01_2017-04-08.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(fn, header=None)

# устанавливаем Timestamp (datetime) в качестве индекса
df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df[0] + ' ' + df[1])).sort_index()

# разбивка по дням недели
(df.groupby(df.index.weekday, as_index=False)
   .apply(lambda x: x.to_csv('d:/temp/aaa/weekday_{}.csv'.format(int(x.name)+1),
                             index=False, header=None))
)

# разбивка по часам
(df.groupby(df.index.hour, as_index=False)
   .apply(lambda x: x.to_csv('d:/temp/aaa/hour_{:02d}.csv'.format(int(x.name)),
                             index=False, header=None))
)
```

Comment: Выручили =) А есть ли возможность допустим взять много файлов из одного места и сразу все так обработать и сохранить?

Comment: @Miroslava, да, в качестве примера можете посмотреть [этот ответ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37648544/how-to-create-custom-dataframe-from-subset-of-csv-file/37652220#37652220)